# How to post/create ServiceNow records from database

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, servicenow

I have four columns in  sql table as CompanyName, CompanyBusinessKey, CompanyType, CreatedDate. I want to post/Create these records into ServiceNow API through SSIS, Script Task. Please let me know possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation tells you how to do this: 
https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/rest_api_doc?v=helsinki&id=r_TableAPI-POST